# How to open an http file with fopen()?

Tags: php, http, http-headers, fopen, fwrite

I need to open a http external xml file, then replace some text and save the file in the hosting of my site.

Somethinkg like this:

```
<?php

$xml_external_path = 'http://someplace.com/external_file.xml';
$xml_external = fopen($xml_external_path, "w+");


//here the code to replace text

$xml_local_path = 'http://www.misite.com/local_file.xml';
$xml_local = fopen($xml_sw_path, "w+");

fwrite($xml_local, $xml_external);

fclose($xml_external);
fclose($xml_local);
?>
```

Problem is that I get this message:

> Warning: fopen(http://someplace.com/external_file.xml): failed to open
>   stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections at...
>
> Warning: fopen(http://someplace.com/local_file.xml): failed to open
>   stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections at...

<strike>Both files are writeable.</strike>

Comment: Did you try to switch your "w+" parameter for other? I would try "c" if I were you. You propably know that you can find these parameters on [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont want to write to the address. Just replace the `+w` with `r`.

```
$xml_external_path = 'http://someplace.com/external_file.xml';
$xml_external = fopen($xml_external_path, "r");
....
```

Have a look at [those](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) examples.

You could also use the [file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function.

```
file_get_contents("http://someplace.com/external_file.xml");
```